# Left join 3 tables error #1066

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to left join 3 table but getting the following error

> "#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'uid'"

I tried some of the suggestions i found online such as using an alias `tbl_add_unit.uid AS UnitUID` but that didn't work.

My code is:

```
SELECT tbl_add_unit.uid, tbl_add_rent.r_unit_no, tbl_add_electricity_bill.unit_no
FROM tbl_add_unit, tbl_add_rent, tbl_add_electricity_bill
LEFT JOIN tbl_add_unit.uid ON tbl_add_rent.r_unit_no
LEFT JOIN tbl_add_unit.uid ON tbl_add_electricity_bill.unit_no;
```

Comment: It is not good to mix implicit (comma) join notation and explcit (JOIN) notation; generally not considered good practice to use implicit joins at all for the last decade or two. ...ah, I see your mistake LEFT JOIN takes a *table* and it's ON clause takes a condition (usually a field equality comparison)

Comment: Not only is not good. It's potentially disastrous

Comment: Also `LEFT JOIN tbl_add_unit.uid` is simply gibberish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation.  Those commas are equivalent to `JOIN` keyword.  And typically, there's a condition used to match the tables, specified in a `ON` clause.

Looks like maybe we were after a result set something like the result that would be returned by a query like this:

```
 SELECT u.uid
      , r.r_unit_no
      , b.unit_no
   FROM tbl_add_unit u
   LEFT
   JOIN tbl_add_rent r
     ON r.r_unit_no = u.uid
   LEFT
   JOIN tbl_add_electricity_bill b
     ON b.unit_no = u.uid
  WHERE ...
  ORDER
     BY ...
```

---

What was the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, let's aim for something more akin to:

```
SELECT tbl_add_unit.uid, tbl_add_rent.r_unit_no, tbl_add_electricity_bill.unit_no
FROM tbl_add_unit
LEFT JOIN tbl_add_rent ON tbl_add_unit.uid = tbl_add_rent.r_unit_no
LEFT JOIN tbl_add_electricity_bill ON tbl_add_unit.uid = 
tbl_add_electricity_bill.unit_no;
```

That assumes what is in the joins is true, so:  tbl_add_unit.uid = tbl_add_rent.r_unit_no and tbl_add_unit.uid = tbl_add_electricity_bill.unit_no.  If that is true, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax of joins should be something like...

```
SELECT some stuff
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.blahA = table2.blahB
JOIN table3 ON table2.blahC = table3.blahD
;
```

`LEFT JOIN` keeps the data from the left side of the join even when there are no matches on the right, `INNER JOIN` only keeps joined data.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, it looks like you have tables separated by comma. I would assume you would just like to join these tables to fetch information. You can just use JOIN statement and specify aliases for each of these tables.

```
SELECT 
   tblAddUnit.uid, tblAddRent.r_unit_no, tblAddElectricityBill.unit_no
FROM 
   tbl_add_unit tblAddUnit 
LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_add_rent tblAddRent ON
   tblAddUnit.uid ON tblAddRent.r_unit_no
LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_add_electricity_bill tblAddElectricityBill ON 
   tblAddElectricityBill.unit_no = tblAddUnit.uid;
```